# FFMPEG Video not working on Social Media Platforms (Flutter-FFMPEG)

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

I am using [Flutter-FFMPEG](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) a Flutter library based on Mobile FFMPEG. I am creating a  video from a list of .bmp images. The video works plays normally in devices media player on android or desktop.

But when I tried to share that video on social media like say Instagram it says file format not supported.

It didn't use to work on WhatsApp but after some googling, I made some changes and it works on WhatsApp and Youtube now but not on Instagram, Linkedin, etc.

```
void _runFFmpeg() async {
    print('Run FFMPEG');
   
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String videoSize = '$ImageWidth:$ImageSize';
    print("${ImageWidth}x$ImageSize");
    var arguments = [
      "-y", // replace output file if it already exists
      "-i", "${output.path}/frame_%d.bmp",
       
      "-s", '${ImageWidth}x$ImageSize',
      "-framerate", "30", // framrate
      
      "-c:v", "libvpx",
      
      '-ab', '128k',
      '-ar', '44100',
      '-strict', 'experimental',
     
      "-vcodec", "libx264",

      "-pixel_format", "yuv420p",

      "-preset", "ultrafast",

      "-tune", "animation",

      "${output.path}/test.mp4"
    ];
   
    await _flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(arguments).then((rc) {
      print('Process done with $rc');
      
    });
```

> - The plugin I am using ([Flutter-FFMPEG](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg)) didn't support libx264
> - I tried using '`-profile:v`' to baseline but that gives an error, saying `Error setting profile to baseline`.
> - Also, I tried to first make a .webm file and then convert that to  mp4. I was also able to use '`-profile:v`' when converting .webm to mp4 and gave no error but the output video didn't work on Social Media platforms.

Comment: I'm not really sure if this applies, but [What are the video upload requirements for IGTV on Instagram?](https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/1038071743007909) shows some requirements.

Comment: Well, my video is in .mp4 format and complies with all standard requirements. Also, the video is just 6 seconds long and is not working at all on Instagram from stories, posts, chat nowhere. It's an FFmpeg encoding problem since I made the video from a list of images using the FFmpeg library.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Lokua, I have added an answer, I processed the faulty video again. The tags to be used depend on ur video type I have all the tags I tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
fixFFMPEG(int imageWidth, int imageSize) async {
    print('Fix FFMPEG');
    var output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var arguments2 = [
      '-y',
      // "-s",
      // '${imageWidth}:$imageSize',
      '-i',
      '${output.path}/testNew.mp4',
      "-framerate", "30", // framrate
      "-vcodec", "h264",
      "-c:v", "libx264rgb",
      "-c:a", 'acc',
      '-ab', '128k',
      '-ar', '44100',
      '-strict', 'experimental',
      // '-c',
      // 'copy',
      // '-strict',
      // '-2',
      "-vprofile",
      "baseline",
      "-level",
      "3.0",
      "-an",
      "-pixel_format", "yuv420p",
      // '-vtag',
      // 'avc1',
      // "-vprofile",
      // "baseline",
      // "-level",
      // "3.0",
      // "-brand", "mp42",
      '${output.path}/fixedvideo1.mp4'
    ];
    // await _flutterFFmpeg
    //     .executeWithArguments(arguments2)
    //     .then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process2 exited with rc $rc"));
  }
```